# Algorithm for planning the creation of an object from dependencies

Tags: algorithm

I am an alchemist. I can make things out of other things according to my recipe book. For instance:

```
 2 lead + 1 bismuth -> 1 carbon
 1 oxygen + 5 hydrogen + 3 nitrogen -> 2 carbon
 5 carbon + 5 titanium -> 1 gold
 ...etc.
```

My recipe book contains thousands of recipes, each of which consumes some discrete amount of one or more inputs and produces a discrete amount of one output. Being a lazy alchemist, I don't want to remember all my recipes. I want to write a computer program to solve this problem for me. The input to the program is a description of what I want, like "2 gold", and a description of what I have in stock, like "5 titanium, 6 lead, 3 bismuth, 2 carbon, 1 gold". The output should be either "cannot be made" or a sequence of instructions for creating the thing. For the example given here, the output could be:

```
make 2 carbon out of 4 lead + 2 bismuth
make 1 gold out of 4 carbon + 4 titanium
```

Then, combined with the 1 gold I already have, I have the 2 gold I wanted.

One last note: the recipes are weighted; e.g. I prefer to make carbon out of lead and bismuth if I can.

Is there an elegant way to formulate and solve this problem? A naive recursive solution looks tempting, but I can think of recipe sets that would cause it to do an exponential amount of work.

(And, as a followup, someday my research might uncover a circular set of recipes---maybe I can make 1 hydrogen out of 1 helium and 1 helium out of 1 hydrogen---and I would like to be able to handle this case as well.)

Comment: Topological sorting is the answer.

Comment: I gave that a little bit of thought and couldn't figure out how to handle the fact that there might be more than one recipe for something. (It's not the topological sorting that isn't clear, but rather, how a topologically sorted set of things can be used to solve the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard.

Given an instance of CNF-SAT, prepare alchemical tables with reagents for

1. each variable
2. each literal
3. each clause (unsatisfied version)
4. each clause (satisfied version)
5. the output.

The reactions are

1. variable to large supply of corresponding positive literal
2. variable to large supply of corresponding negative literal
3. clause (unsatisfied version) and satisfying literal to clause (satisfied version)
4. all clauses (satisfied versions) to the output.

The question is whether we can make the output given one of each variable and one of each clause (unsatisfied version).

This problem is related to the problem of determining reachability of vector addition systems/Petri nets; my reduction is based in part on reductions that appeared in that literature.

Comment: I had to go work it out on paper to convince myself that you are correct, but now I'm quite sure you are. Very nice reduction. :)

Comment: I also have to thank you for mentioning Petri nets --- I've never heard of them and they look like exactly the generalization I was looking for.